# What is the Property and HasRequired Keyword in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I m working with code first approach with MVC but what is Property and haskeyrequired Keyword used when generating a database.

Code:

```
   public class StudentDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentDBContext() : base("StudentDBContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> course { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //course
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasKey(p => p.CourseId); //Primary Key field in a database
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().Property(c => c.CourseId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            //student
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(b => b.Id);   //Student Id
                                           //what is property keyword?
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(b => b.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

                                          //what is hasrequired keyword?
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasRequired(p => p.course).WithMany(b => b.student).HasForeignKey(b => b.CourseId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

why it is used property and hasrequired keyword meaning in asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 1):

See [EF6 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) for more information. You can read about [HasRequired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-required-to-optional-relationship-one-tozero-or-one) and [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#property-mapping) methods there as well.

Comment: I refer this link it is fluent api. what is fluent api? can you give suggestion what fluent api in my above model class?

Comment: @rahulpatil Just read the documentation before starting working with EF6, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

*property* is used to reference a property and *hasrequired* is used to force required rule on that property. see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships.